# How can I pass instance via apply_filters as a parameter?

Tags: filters, parameter

How can I pass instance via apply_filters as a parameter?

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($timezone_string));
$d = apply_filters( 'custom_date_format', $d, $dt );
```

UPDATE: It's my mistake. Instance can be a parameter in PHP.

Comment: Instance of what? To do what with? You’re currently passing a DateTime instance as the second argument. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Where does `$d` come from? I think your code snippet is incomplete :( can you use the edit link under the tags to update your question so it's clearer?

Comment: @JacobPeattie; @TomJNowell
I'm sorry, it's my mistake. There was an error on my filters and thought that I could not pass an instance as a parameter. After I did debug, the callback function's name was mistyping. I'm sorry and thank you for your comments.